# How to get only the local time pattern and only the local date pattern?

Tags: java, android, date

I have a time picker in android. When the user chooses the time, it is returned two integers (hourOfDay and minute) through onTimeSet method. Its signature is shown bellow:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute);
```

What I want is to show to the user the chosen time **in the local pattern**. So, in Brazil or France, the time should be seen as 14:30, while in the US, 2:30 PM. At the moment I'm using joda-time library and not LocalTime, because android does not support the last one. If I can get the String pattern of time the problem is solved, because I can call the toString(String pattern) method.

```
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minute);
localTime.toString(pattern /* to be found */)
```

I have the same problem with another Picker. The user chooses the **date**  and year, month and dayOfMonth are returned. In this case, in Brazil or France the date should be display as 12/01/2000 while in the US 1/12/2000.

How can I solve this? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tip: Use the term *[localized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)* when referring to strings formatted using a particular human language for translation and certain cultural norms for abbreviation/punctuation/ordering. The term “local” in date-time work often means “without any offset-from-UTC, without any time zone”, an altogether different matter. In java.time, the classes named with `Local…` (`LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, and `LocalDateTime`) all mean no-offset-nor-zone — their naming has nothing to do with localization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Joda-Time library is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

Use the java.time framework of the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 23 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );

Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

Adjust to suit your taste by calling `ofLocalizedDate` or `ofLocalizedTime`, using other `FormatStyle` objects, other `Locale` objects, other zones.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).